# What's the source for Epic Mystic Theurge progression?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

It's not in the ELH, or the Errata (that I can see). I'm not seeing it the PHB or DMG from the 2012 reprint either.

It doesn't seem like it's just a logical extension of the rules applied to any given prestige class with 10 levels as there is the curious alternating progression for spells/day on odd/even levels ... so where did it come from? Am I blind? Or does this curiosity only exist in the 3.5 PHB/DMG and not in the 2012 reprints?

Comment: Hi McCloud, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] when you can, it'll help give you an idea of how things tend to work here, since we tend to be different to other sites. It sounds like you've heard of or seen that there is such a progression somewhere - it might help to say what makes you confident it exists, since if it doesn't actually exist people could give you an idea of what you did see.

Comment: @doppelgreener Most likely he’s referring to [the one on the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/prestigeClassProgressions.htm#epicMysticTheurge), which is indeed nonsense. But I’m also about 90% sure it actually is in *Epic Level Handbook*, though I’ll have to wait until I get home to double-check it.

Comment: It's not in the 3.5 ELH.  It's also not in the 3.0 ELH, any edition of the PHB or DMG I could find, any of the Epic Insights articles, or as far as I can tell anything else that isn't obviously lifted straight from the d20 SRD.

I think it might just be made up.  But I'm not certain enough of that to post it as an answer.

Comment: Okay, it IS in the real SRD (the one published directly by WotC), not just made up for the online one.  See answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source of the epic mystic theurge progression was the [“Free D&D® V.3.5 Accessory Update *Epic Level Handbook*”](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a)

The epic mystic theurge listed on pages 5 and 6 matches what appears in the SRD, including the odd-level increases to arcane spellcasting and even-level increases to divine spellcasting.

Comment: KRyan wins!  Deleting my answer.  My google-fu was not strong enough.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Just wanted to be on firm ground when deciding to allow or not allow an Epic Theurge. Weird that they didn't reincorporate this into the 2012 reprints though.

Comment: @McCloud Well, that’s not what you asked. The answer to *that* is “no,” because you shouldn’t allow epic anything—the epic rules are so incredibly worthless and incapable of delivering on their promise that I consider *Epic Level Handbook* to almost be a scam.